# Angular does not iterate over array correctly

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an very easy looking problem. But im not able to find the solution since hours.

Have a look at this code:

```
      {{stockLocations[1].name}}
    <select #storageLocationSelection
            (change)="onStorageLocation(storageLocationSelection.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let user of stockLocations; index as i; first as isFirst">
        dfgfdsgdfg
      </option>
      <option value="1">Lakers</option>
      <option>Miami</option>
      <option>Cleveland</option>
    </select>
```

The corresponding output looks like this:

[image]

As soon as i add any kind of output, like the index:

```
      {{stockLocations[1].name}}
    <select #storageLocationSelection
            (change)="onStorageLocation(storageLocationSelection.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let user of stockLocations; index as i; first as isFirst">
        {{i}} dfgfdsgdfg
      </option>
      <option value="1">Lakers</option>
      <option>Miami</option>
      <option>Cleveland</option>
    </select>
```

The whole selection line is empty

[image]

This is how i defined the array:

```
  stockLocations: StockLocation[] = [{id: 1, name: "ABC"}, {id: 2, name: "DD"}];
```

You can also see the "DD" beneath the button. This is a test to see, whether the array is accessible properly.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks

Comment: It is working just fine when I copy over your code to a fresh stackblitz. Is this by any chance a caching issue and can be solved by restarting the server? If not, can you provide the rest of the HTML in question (and possibly even the resulting raw HTML)?

Comment: Is there an issue with the content overflowing? if you just have `<option ...>  {{i}}</option>` does that show the indices?

Comment: [check me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ys9vg?file=src/app/app.component.ts). check this example I can't see any issue here, just copied your code and tested